# PHP Instant messenger

Tags: php, sql, messenger

I am trying to make a messenger using PHP and SQL
This is my code

```
    <form action="send_post.php" method="post">
    <h3>Name:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <h3>Message:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, message FROM chat";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                while(1){
                        ob_start();
                        echo "" . $row["name"]. " - " . $row["message"]. "<br>";

                        sleep(10);
                        echo "" . $row["name"]. " - " . $row["message"]. "<br>";
                        ob_end_clean();

}
} 
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

However this does not work, is there any reason for this?
The problems started once I added the infinite while loop to refresh the messages.

Comment: while(1){  remove this loop

Comment: But I want the query to automatically refresh

Comment: How does it not work?  What did you expect it to do? What is it doing wrong? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It gives a 500 error. I expected it to automatically refresh the query. It is not refreshing the query

Comment: The code you've done does not collect new updates from the database. Once you `SELECT` something, database calculates the result and sends it back. It doesn't keep a "live" connection to the table and hand out new updates. I suggest that you scratch this and check how other people implement chat mechanisms.

Comment: You can't accomplish what you are trying to do with just php/mysql. You are going to have to write some javascript ajax goodness to pull new messages. Server side languages are not going to work by themselves because they need to fully execute before the client gets any response, which isn't going to happen if you have the script in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP works serversided, which means that the client(guest) requests a page that the server then "compiles" to then send to the client as a clientsided language such as HTML. If the PHP code never reaches an end/stop the client browser is going to think the server stopped responding and give an error.

To achieve what you are trying to do you might want to look into something like [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which allows for the client to fetch data from the server seperatly from the main request. That way you can have one file showing only the messages and request that file on a timer, while having the form as usual page load. You can however also make the form dynamic using [JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**UPDATE** You can look at this [blogpost](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/) to get an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, because this is the correct answer, so I figured I'd at least put you back to even votes.

Comment: Well an example would be nice to state his answer :)